# Can a dog that has had all his shots for parvo, still contract it?

Tags: diseases, dogs

I have a 1.5 year old Boston terrier who when he was a puppy got all his shots, including 3 for parvo. My roommate recently got a puppy. 10 weeks old? it was sick and when the vet checked he was confirmed for parvo. My dog has been playing with him and sharing toys/water/food with this puppy(possibly even ate his poop) is he at risk for parvo? I'm so scared for my boston. I hope this is the right section.

Comment: Have you asked your vet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parvovirus most commonly affects unvaccinated puppies less than 6 months of age. However, no vaccine is 100% effective, and vaccinated adult dogs can much less commonly be infected.

Even though the risk may be low in a vaccinated dog, I would still take your dog to see a veterinarian. They can perform a Parvovirus SNAP test. If your dog is in the early infection stages, he may not be shedding the virus in large quantities in the faeces yet. In this case your veterinarian may recommend a blood test (complete blood count). Since parvovirus typically affects the bone marrow first, a low white blood cell count could be an early indicator of infection.

Parvovirus can live in the environment for many months, so make sure to disinfect and clean all surfaces with a dilute bleach solution – especially toys, bowls, etc.